# How to run another function after an async function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I would like to have the function `toggle()`  run after `search()`, but the function `this.toggle(element)` is not executed after `this.search()`.

```
addElement(element) {
  element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded;
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
    width: '300px',
    data: element
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
    if (result==true) {
      await this.search();
      this.toggle(element);
    }
  });
}

public search() {
this.productService.findByLabel(this.label)
.subscribe(
  res=> {
    this. dataSourceProduct.data = res as Product[];
  },
  (error) => {
    this.errorService.handleError(error);
  })
}

toggle(element) {
  let elements = this.dataSourceProduct.data.filter(x => x.id ===   element.id);
  elements.forEach((element: any) => {
  element.isExpanded = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks good, `this.toggle(element)` method will execute after `await this.search()` method. You just need to make sure that `this.search()` returns a promise. Can you also post `this.search()` method implementation?

Comment: public search() {
this.productService.findByLabel(this.label)
.subscribe(
  res=> {
    this. dataSourceProduct.data = res as Product[];
  },
  (error) => {
    this.errorService.handleError(error);
  })

}

Answer (score 0):

After calling `search()`, the product list is displayed. But the next step after that should be that next function: `toggle(element)` will run, but it is not running, only the list of products is displayed.

```
  public search() {
    this.productService.findByLabel(this.label)
    .subscribe(
      res=> {
        this. dataSourceProduct.data = res as Product[];
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorService.handleError(error);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise` for this.

```
>   public search() {
> 
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>       this.productService.findByLabel(this.label).subscribe(res => {
>         this.dataSourceProduct.data = res as Product[];
>         resolve()
>       }, (error) => {
>         this.errorService.handleError(error);
>         reject()
>       })
>     })   }
```

- use your search function like this

  > this.search().then(res => {
  > //toggle function   }, reject => {
  > //error}    )}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```js
addElement(element) {
  element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded;
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
    width: '300px',
    data: element
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result == true) {
      this.search().then(() => {
        this.toggle(element);
      }).catch((error) => console.error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: But 'this.productService.findByLabel()' returns observable, can he call '.then' for that?

Comment: no it should subscribe on 'this.productService.findByLabel()' when i ansewer the question she don't share 'share()' function

Answer (score -1):

what is the return of this.search() ? it should be a promise or an observable to inform your code when this function ends and you it can continue executing next line.

If you use an observable you have to use subscribe instead of await.
With promises you can also use .then

Comment: umm after checking google i can see this is my point of view, I will remove it from answer

Comment: You can only await method which returns a promise, it cannot be awaited if it returns an observable.